# Browser doesn't show utf-8 characters

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, mysqli

I have some `php` files that have utf-8 characters in. The files are saved with the `utf-8` encoding. I am also specifically setting the page `charset` to UTF-8. Browser shows them correctly if directly output in the source code. But when getting field data from my `MySQL` tables (using `mysqli` connection), question marks are displayed instead of content. Does anyone know what it could be? I am assuming it has to do with the database interaction?

HTTP Response header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 18 Feb 2013 23:05:13 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.4.9
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.9
Content-Length: 2161
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Comment: Is the data stored in your database in utf 8?

Comment: Perhaps you forgot `$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');`?

Comment: did you output the text from DB in console at runtime and check what is being retrieved from DB

Comment: sounds like perhaps mysql isn't storing in UTF-8, or your driver isn't retrieving the data as UTF-8. this may help you out: http://cameronyule.com/2008/07/configuring-mysql-to-use-utf-8/

Comment: thanks for all of you guys. @BenjaminGruenbaum yes the data is stored in utf8, that was not the problem. I tried your link @JoshuaBurns but for some reason I got error when trying to start mysql server with those settings in the `my.cnf` file. `mysqli->set_charset()` did the job :)

Comment: FWIW: If anyone else like me was having trouble with utf-8 values in a mysql db being properly DISPLAYED as HTML, this web page fixed me right up: http://www.webmastertools.bz/how-to-display-utf-8-characters-web-page/ It's not enough just to get the chars correct in the db--you still gotta display those rascals on the frontend!

Answer (score 0):

reinstall mysql server and enable utf-8 supporting , this usually happens on localhost

Comment: reinstall?? why not just change settings? reinstalling is like turning your computer off and on again for not deleting a character :D